# Find formula for sum of 0,1/n

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to express the following with a formula I can use programmatically:

```
P    F     X
---------
1   0,1/1 = 0,1
2   0,1/2 = 0,05
3   0,1/3 = 0,033
Summ      = 0,183
```

So basically it is the sum
$$0,1/1 + 0,1/2 + 0,1/3 + 0,1/n ...$$

How could that be calculated in a formula which depends on n?

My goal is to express the Sum for an input of n.

E.g. $$n=3 \implies 0,183$$

Comment: How quickly do you need this done? I would think for most applications you'd be just fine summing the terms since it's just linear time.

Comment: In the end I am going to place this in a MySQL stored procedure that caluclates it for millions of rows. So I am looking for something like SELECT  0.1 * (n *... ) | n is known and stored inside a table.

Comment: There is no formula for this sum. In a programming context the easiest thing would be a for loop for k from 1 to n with sum = sum +1/k inside it. Your table storage solution looks like a poor option.

Comment: I see, yeah that is a bit more intensive than I had in mind. Do your n's follow any specific pattern? If so, do you think there's any way you could save the results from one calculation to use in the next, so that you didn't have to start from the beginning every time?

Comment: Brian had a good idea for a work around. I only need this for n=1-100. So a look up table might be a solution where I simply do an inner join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to approximate it using logarithms, but the only "exact closed form" is a bit of a cheat.  We write $H_n = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$, so your sum would be written $\frac{1}{10}H_n$

---

*From the comments, where we discussed calculating $H_n$:*

For small values of $n$, just calculate $H_n$ manually.  If there's a reason these values would need to be referenced **many** times, make a lookup table for $H_n$ for smaller values of $n$.

For larger values of $n$, you are likely to run into floating-point arithmetic concerns to minimize error (breaking up the sum into blocks, the order of summation, etc.), so the computation eventually becomes tedious.  In that case, I'd instead use the estimate given by $$H_n \approx \ln(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{12n^2}$$
where $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: @merlin See the [Wikipedia page about $H_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) for some discussions about methods of approximation, or to simply despair that there is no simpler way to produce an exact value. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the help. And how would you express Hn? In the end I need to find a MySQL query that tells me the result for an input of n. e.g. For 3 input I would expect 0,183. => SELECT 0,1* (n *... )

Comment: A lookup table is a good idea as a work around. I only need it for 1-100

Comment: @merlin For just up to 100, I would expect just calculating it would be quickest and simplest.  I'd only consider a table if I needed far more terms.  Even then, it would not be complete, it would just be various partial sums such as every 1000.

Comment: Fantastic! No idea how you came up with this, but it looks like this really works. In excel a test for n=4 as a formula looks promising: =1/10 * (LN(4)+0,5772156649+(1/(2*4))-(1/(12*4^2)))

Comment: [Moved my comments into the post]